# Xamarin.UITest: How To Retrieve Coordinates of Device Display

Tags: c#, xamarin, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I am writing a UITest in C# using Xamarin.UITest.

How can I retrieve the coordinates of the device's screen dynamically in the UITest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xamarin.UITest, when you call `app.Query()`, the first query result will return the device display. You can then grab the XY coordinates using the `Rect` property.

Below is a sample REPL output showing the result of `app.Query().First()`, and sample code assigning the XY coordinates to variables in your UITest.

## Sample Output from REPL

[image: Output From REPL]

## Sample Code

```
var windowQuery = app.Query().First();

var topLeftXCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.X;
var topLeftYCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.Y;

var topRightXCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.X + windowQuery.Rect.Width;
var topRightYCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.Y;

var bottomLeftXCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.X;
var bottomLeftYCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.Y + windowQuery.Rect.Height;

var bottomRightXCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.X + windowQuery.Rect.Width;
var bottomRightYCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.Y + windowQuery.Rect.Height;

var centerXCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.CenterX;
var centerYCoordinate = windowQuery.Rect.CenterY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Brandon's answer works well, but `app.Query()` without a predicate is *painfully* slow, since it returns an array and not an `IEnumerable<AppResult>` - in the app I'm currently working with it takes *~10 seconds*.

As a faster alternative, you can specify the automation ID (or some other predicate) of an element you know to be near the root. For example, assuming your views are using `ContentPage`, you can use:

```
var content = app.Query("content").First();
var rect = content.Rect;
```

This completes in less than 1s.

Do note that this won't give you the precise display size - it's the size of the `ContentPage`, so it will be slightly smaller than the display size (but for my use case, that's fine).